# Returning View from ViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a function that returns a view to be displayed. When I use:

```
UIViewController* vcontroller= [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"meterEnlarge"];
return vcontroller.view;
```

I see the view. However, when I do:

```
ViewController_Meter_Enlarge_iPad* controller = [[ViewController_Meter_Enlarge_iPad alloc]init];
return controller.view;
```

I don't see the view. Considering I need to modify properties on the VC the second option is critical to me (as I start calling [controller setxyz], etc). How can I return the view from the VC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `view` won't be set unless you create the view controller and initialize it from a NIB file:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
```

([reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle%3a))

(or manually assign a view to the view controller).

Comment: or from the storyboard.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I take it that you expect the first view controller (the one from the storyboard) to be of your custom view controller class? In that case, you can check the actual class of the view controller returned to you from the storyboard, and do your custom setup if it matches the class that you want:

```
UIViewController *storyboardVC = 
    [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"meterEnlarge"];

if ([storyboardVC isKindOfClass:[ViewController_Meter_Enlarge_iPad class]]) {
    ViewController_Meter_Enlarge_iPad *customVC = 
        (ViewController_Meter_Enlarge_iPad *)storyboardVC;

    [customVC setXYZ:@"foo"];
}
```